# how to populate items for custom popup menu from database?

Tags: android, xml

I know the normal popup menu populating from menu.xml.

Now I want to populate custom popup menu, like onclick on button should generate popup menus from single column values of database table.
please some body help me out, I am stuck with this.

And excuse my English .

code is :

```
      onClick()
        {

       //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(CookBookActivity.this, btnPlayBack);
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate("database column values", popup.getMenu());

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(CookBookActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

                     }
            });
            popup.show();
  }
```

I want single column records of database table should be display in popup menu.

Comment: What menu?  What calass are you talking about?

Comment: wait i'll add my code which 'll help you.

Comment: you can call popup.getMenu() to get underlying  Menu object and then you can call one of its add() methods

Comment: Can you give me sample code snipshot pls.@ pskink

Comment: popup.getMenu().add(itemString)

Comment: thank you for your valuable response @ pskink.